# How to ignore or handle django-hijack from the command line?

Tags: django, command-line, django-tests

I'm writing some unit tests for an existing django project that has had no unit tests to date.

When I run the tests from the command line using

```
  ./manage.py test
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named hijack
```

Now hijack is actually installed as I can use it from the browser when I run the server using

```
./manage.py runserver
```

The contents of manage.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mtmdjango.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

So ... how I can disable the reference for hijack when running tests or how can I enable hijack to be available under the command line when running tests?

(can someone create and add the tag django-hijack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked through the tutorials at

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/ through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial05/

It turned out my command line was wrong.

```
python manage.py test contacts
```

gives me the output I was expecting.